# Problem with Redux: it shows me wrong info with Axios-Thunk

Tags: react-native, react-redux, axios, expo, redux-thunk

i'm using Redux with Axios and redux-thunk in an Expo application. Then i'm doing a payment list with a Button navigating to another component to "Report a payment". And in this form I wish to get currencies from api and when user selects one of them get payMethods for this currency. All these lists are separated in 3 different reducers like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import actions from '../types/fetchs';
import uri from '../address';

export const fetchMethodsStarted = () => ({ type : actions.FETCH_REQUEST_STARTED });
export const fetchMethodsSuccess = meths => ({ type : actions.FETCH_REQUEST_SUCCEED, payload : meths });
export const fetchMethodsFailure = error => ({ type : actions.FETCH_REQUEST_FAILURE, payload : error });

export const fetchMethods = id => {
  return dispatch => {
    axios.get(uri + `/web/currencies/${id}/methods`).then(methods => {
      dispatch(fetchMethodsSuccess(methods.data.slice()));
    }).catch(error => {
      dispatch(fetchMethodsFailure(error.message));
    });
  }
}

import actions from '../types/fetchs';

const initialState = {
  FETCH_REQUEST_STARTED : false,
  FETCH_REQUEST_FAILURE : false,
  FETCH_REQUEST_SUCCEED : false,
  methods : [],
  ERROR_MESSAGE : ''
};

export const reduceMethods = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case actions.FETCH_REQUEST_STARTED : return ({
      FETCH_REQUEST_STARTED : true,
      FETCH_REQUEST_FAILURE : false,
      FETCH_REQUEST_SUCCEED : false,
      methods : [],
      ERROR_MESSAGE : ''
    });
    case actions.FETCH_REQUEST_FAILURE : return ({
      FETCH_REQUEST_STARTED : false,
      FETCH_REQUEST_FAILURE : true,
      FETCH_REQUEST_SUCCEED : false,
      methods : [],
      ERROR_MESSAGE : action.payload
    });
    case actions.FETCH_REQUEST_SUCCEED : return ({
      FETCH_REQUEST_STARTED : false,
      FETCH_REQUEST_FAILURE : false,
      FETCH_REQUEST_SUCCEED : true,
      methods : action.payload,
      ERROR_MESSAGE : ''
    });
    default : return state;
  }
}
```

But every time I dispatch an action to change one array, all arrays are modified, thinking it was Axios I used Array.slice() to build new arrays everytime but error remains.. so I can't access all data in same component, can anyone imagine how to avoid this behavior?

Comment: All reducers are executed on **every** action, you can make a specific action type for each data type like `FETCh_CITIES_STARTED` or give the action a `dataType` so your reducer can conditionally do something: `if(action.payload.dataType===CITIES){...only do something with state here} return state;`

Comment: Ok, goin to change all reducers, TY